# How to add textures to faces that are facing a certain direction

Tags: texturing, faces

Basically I have a crude maze-like object, but I want the textures of the floor and walls to be different.  How would I go about placing a texture on all faces point north, etc.

Assume I am a beginner, please.

Comment: cycles, BI or BGE? and are you talking about one material, or different materials on the floors and walls?

Comment: Not entirely sure, my intention is to import it into Unity, so whichever accomplishes that? If I'm understanding the question at all, I apologize for my lack of knowledge right now--I will do more research later it's just all very confusing.  And they are all one material I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple materials assigned, you can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to activate the **Select Similar** menu.  For selecting all of the floor area, using **Normal** works well.  You only have to select one face and all others that have a similar normal should be selected automatically by the tool.  There is a slider that controls a threshold value that you can adjust to change the angle overlap.

Once all the faces for that area are selected, you can select the appropriate material and press the **Assign** button.

[image]

For the textures, I used the *Box* setting which maps the texture from all directions if you add a Texture Coordinates node and set the Input for the texture to **Object**.

[image]

Here is a copy of the .blend file so you can have a closer look. :)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In Cycles you can make a node setup like this:

[image: Color from normal direction]

What's happening is the Geometry node is providing the object's normal data (information about the directions its faces are pointing) in the form of color values. The Separate XYZ node is taking that all in but only returning the values for the Z axis (up and down). That data is then being used to factor between the red and blue.

In this example the factor is mixing two shader nodes, but it could just as easily be color nodes or any node that can receive a factor input.

If you wanted to change the direction you could use X or Y outputs instead of Z.